# Replacing a value with gsub does not seem to work

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing values like this:

```
 list <- c("?stanbul", "Ba?ak?ehir")
```

What I would like to do now is to replace these values with a space ("").

So therefore I do

```
list <- gsub("?", "", list)
```

But this gives me this output:

```
> list
[1] "?stanbul"   "Ba?ak?ehir"
```

Any thoughts how I can tackle this?

Comment: Try `gsub("[?]", "", list)` or `gsub("?", "", list, fixed = TRUE)`. The `?` is a special character.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this `list <- gsub("\\?", "", list)`. From the manual of `regex`:

> Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it
>   with a backslash. The metacharacters in extended regular expressions
>   are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?, but note that whether these have a
>   special meaning depends on the context.